# How to include an external javascript file when using ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm using ExtJs 4.2.2 and included all necessary js and css files, and my codes work just fine, ONLY IF I write my code into script tags within my html file. When I try to put these code into another file with .js extension and include it between head tags properly, it returns nothing. I'm sure I've included my js file properly because when I fill it with standard js codes, I get results. But with ExtJS syntax, the same code which return results within script tags, returns nothing. How? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The following two are equivalent. If one works, the others work, too, regardless of what js code you use:

(Ex 1.)

```
<html><head>
<script>//your js code here</script>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

and

(Ex 2.)

```
<html><head>
<script src="jscode.js"></script>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

where jscode.js contains

```
// your js code here
```

Furthermore, the following two are equivalent:

(Ex 3.)

```
<html><head>
</head><body>
<script>//your js code here</script>
</body></html>
```

and

(Ex 4.)

```
<html><head>
</head><body>
<script src="jscode.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

NOTHING will change in behaviour.

I think (but you didnt post ANY code at all, so it's jsut guessing) that you had Example 3 working, but changed to Example 2. But only 3 and 4 are equivalent! And now you call that ExtJS fault!

Comment: Thanks for your help. But let's say I'm writing an application which has a lot of ExtJs code, and let's say if I wrote all of those codes in Html file, there would be a difficulty of working neatly, cause it would be a 'mess'. So I decided writing every section to a different js file and call them in html file. That was my point. Thank you anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

You are executing code in an onLoad event or a Load event, perhaps like:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('p').css('');
})
```

Remove this section and use only this in the javascript file and include it in a <Head> section:

```
$('p').css('');
```

When you are coding in html, then it execute steps one by one. But when we use a separate file then it executes it slower than HTML code.

I think I can use those technique mentioned on the top.

I am sure it will work.

Comment: I don't use jquery syntax and any onLoad event. I simply include my .js file with extjs code in it, in the head section and nothing happens. I'm asking is it a special case to ExtJs?